# Typescript recognising wrong type in promise resolve

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea, ionic-framework

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA and in my Ionic App I have the following functions

```
private loadToken() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.storage.get('token').then(token=> {
      resolve(token && tokenNotExpired('token',token) ? token : null);
    });
  });
}
public authHeader() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.loadToken().then(token => {
      console.log(typeof token); //Returning 'string'
      let options = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', token) //token is underlined in red
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The function works fine, but my IDE underlines token in red and says:

```
Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[]' ...
```

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(token)` and post an example? Clearly the `token` is not a plain string.

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS Unfortunately, it is. Console.log returns "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5c..."

Comment: What is the return type of the `this.storage.get()` method? I usually explicitly mention the return type of functions like `private loadToken(): Promise<string>{ }` just to be on the safer side. Try doing that and see if the linter catches the error earlier.

Comment: @RajshriMohanKS Working perfectly now, you're awesome.

Comment: Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code : `return new Promise(resolve => {`

Needs an explicit annotation

```
return new Promise<string>(resolve => {
```

## Why

Because they type cannot be inferred and hence resolves to `{}`.